# Comparing lines of text based on words inside the lines Java

Tags: java, string

I need to read lines of text from a file that i have prompted from the user. My java program is supposed to read the first line of this file and check to see if the last word of that line appears anywhere in the second line. without using repetition, arrays, or class construction I have come up with this so far:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter filename: ");

    File userFile = new File(keyboard.nextLine());

    keyboard.close();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(userFile);

    String firstLine = input.nextLine();
    String secondLine = input.nextLine();
```

After here I have tried a lot of String methods but nothing is giving me back a satisfying result. I know I will need to finish my program with an if and else statement about whether or not the second line contains the last word in the first line.

**Having trouble finding a way to compare substrings (words within a line of text) that I do not actually know the location of or what the chars are. This is due to the fact that all the input is user generated. Is there even a way to compare substrings while retaining the actual chars and not converting to ints??

**UPDATE I AM ECSTATIC this is how I have solved this frustrating problem:

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.println("Enter filename: ");

    File userFile = new File(keyboard.nextLine());

    keyboard.close();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(userFile);

    String firstLine = input.nextLine();
    String secondLine = input.nextLine();

    int lastWordIndex;

    lastWordIndex = ((firstLine.lastIndexOf(" ")) + 1);

    String lastWord = firstLine.substring(lastWordIndex);

    if (secondLine.contains(lastWord))
        System.out.println("It is true the word " + lastWord
                + " appears in the text: " + secondLine);
    else
        System.out.println("The word: " + lastWord
                + " does not appear in the text: " + secondLine);
```

Comment: Have you tried [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and [`String.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: Yes but the problem here is that I do not know what the lines contain I just know that I need to figure out if that last word (which is delimited by a space and can technically be alphanumeric with caps) of the first string appears anywhere in the second line.
Samples
input: 
computer programming is h4Rd
econ is also very h4Rd
output: It is true that the word haRd appears in the text: econ is also very h4Rd

Comment: again can you post up your file content? your input and expected output? so we can reproduce your code and help you better. can you explain " I need to read lines of text from a file that i have prompted from the user."?

Comment: Do you want to check every line - ie that any line in he file contains the last word of the previous line, or are there literally only two lines in the file?

Comment: there should only be two lines in the file to make it "easier" I think the problem here boils down to the fact that as soon as I use lastIndexOf of substring() or anything else that may tell me where the last word is I am left with an int and I just want that substring. obviously I would just use substring if i knew the actual string but because it is from a "user's file" i don't actually know anything about the strings. @Bohemian

Comment: For future reference, when solving these kinds of problems, I strongly suggest stepping away from the computer and describing **in English** the steps needed to solve the problem. From there, you can look at the methods available in the Java API to help you implement those steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods to do this, but you need to get the last word in the firstLine string, then compare it with the secondLine string.

You can use the `substring()` method on your line, then use the `lastIndexOf()` method with the argument " " (i.e. whitespace). If you add one to this you will have the index of the first letter of the last word in your string.

Comment: as the op said, he or she is aware of it but it seems the op has another issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
String lastWord = firstLine.replaceAll(".*\\s+", "");
boolean secondLineHasLastWord = secondLine.contains(lastWord);
```

or, to in-line it:

```
if (secondLine.contains(firstLine.replaceAll(".*\\s+", ""))) {
    // yes
} else {
    // no
}
```

Extracting the last word is done using a regex that matches everything up to and including the last whitespace character and replaces the match with nothing (effectively deleting it).